# List.JS doesn't work when injected via a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, list, google-chrome-extension

I failed to spot a similar question - I did searched this topic extensively on SO and Google, and could not find an answer to it.

This is my conundrum:

1. I have a set page containing a table
2. I want to make that table searchable (not sortable, just searchable)
3. I am injecting some JS code directly into page, with a script specified in Manifest.JS, and this script is cloning the table into a `DIV` with the correct class, is adding the 'list' class to the table's body, and the corresponding classes to table body 'td' elements - just one column on which I want to do the search on.
4. Next step involves clicking on extension's icon, performing a loop XHR request (sadly synchro, as I could not get my head around how to make it async) and that table's rows are coloured and some 'td' cells populated. I want to be able to filter the table based on those 'td' new  content.

No matter if I put the

```
 var options = {
        valueNames: ["searchterm"]
        };
    var eventsList = new List("events", options);
```

in the pre-injected code specified in manifest.js, or in the other script which runs when clicking extension's icon, I get the same error in Chrome console:

```
'Uncaught ReferenceError: List is not defined'
```

Update: Code is below.

How could I make that table searchable? What am I doing wrong, and what should be injected or written before what?

Code as follows:

Html:

---

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv = "Content-Type" content = "text/html; charset = utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<title> a title</title>
<table>a table</table>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>someContent</th>
/*14 <th> elements corresponding to 14 columns, the last one being: */
<th>contentIWantToSearch</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr id = "some ID" class = "someClass" style = "someStyle">
/*14 <td> elements, with the last one being:*/
<td> the actual content I want to filter the table after</td>
</tr>
/*next, a long list of <tr>s, same structure, part of the table */
</tbody>
<tfoot>
/*one <tr>, 11 <td> */
</tfoot>
</table>
</body>
```

Chrome Extension Manifest (Manifest.JSON)

---

```
[...]
"permissions": [
"URL I want it to inject the script automatically",
"declarativeContent"
],
"background": {
"scripts": ["background.js"],
"persistent": false
},
"content_scripts": [
{
"matches": ["URL I want to run it on*"],
"js": ["includedstuff.js"],
"css": ["list.css", "someothercss"]
}
[... rest of manifest.json
```

---

### INCLUDEDSTUFF.JS

```
/*appending the list.js CDN on page load*/
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.1.1/list.min.js";
head.appendChild(script);
/*creating the required list.js classes, only for pages with the structure mentioned above - I cannot match it perfectly based on URL*/
if(document.getElementsByTagName("table").length >1) {
var fulltable = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[1];
var searchboxelem = document.createElement("input");
var events = document.createElement("div");
events.id = "events";
searchboxelem.setAttribute("class", "search");
searchboxelem.setAttribute("placeholder", "Input Search Term");
events.appendChild(searchboxelem);
events.appendChild(fulltable.cloneNode(true));
fulltable.parentNode.replaceChild(events, fulltable);
var defineachrow = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[1].getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");

document.getElementsByTagName("table")[1].getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].setAttribute("class", "list");

for(x=0; x<defineachrow.length; x++) {
defineachrow[x].getElementsByTagName("td")[13].setAttribute("class", "searchterm");
}

}
```

---

content_script.js:

---

```
/*some script with XHR loop requests - and sadly sync, as I could not get around it to make it async, it works however, and then:*/
var options = {
valueNames:["searchterm"]
};
var eventsList = new List("events", options);
```

---

### background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onCLicked.addListener(
function(tab) {
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file:
"content_script.js"});
});
```

Comment: First off, make sure you're calling all scripts with correct "names". Do you really mean `manifest.js` or `manifest.json`? Take a look at the [extension architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch). Take note of [isolated world](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment) concept. And yes, include relevant code.

Comment: By the way, reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide won't hurt (your question is not very bad though, it just lacks relevant code and contains noise such as "my first post" and "many thanks")

Comment: It won't let me edit it, or add code.

Comment: This is not the relevant code. So this is a webpage you're injecting to? It already has `list.js`? What's your manifest?

Comment: I could not edit it the first time due to some access permissions on my network - and then I edited it on parts, to make usre I get the formatting right.

Comment: Where does `content_script.js` ever appear?

Comment: noise removed as well, I hope I am within the guidelines, and someone can help me.

Comment: content script is part of Chrome extension, and it kicks in once the Extension icon is clicked - it performs a set of XHR requests and brings some more data into that table

Comment: By `chrome.tabs.executeScript` or otherwise?

Comment: I will add background.js script as well to the post body

Comment: Please include ONLY relevant parts, and show HTML code as it is before your content scripts inject.

Comment: edited - Html is now as before any code is injected to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grasp the concept of [isolated world](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment):

> Content scripts execute in a special environment called an isolated world. They have access to the DOM of the page they are injected into, but not to any JavaScript variables or functions created by the page. It looks to each content script as if there is no other JavaScript executing on the page it is running on. The same is true in reverse: JavaScript running on the page cannot call any functions or access any variables defined by content scripts.

When your `includedstuff.js` is first injected, a separate JS context is created for the document and it's executed in it.

However, when you insert a `<script>` tag, that executes the code in the page's context. As a result, all the `List` stuff is only visible to the page itself.

When your `content_script` executes, it's executed in the same context as `includedstuff.js`, which does not include `List`.

---

Morale of the story: do you really need to expose `List` to the page? Probably not - you add it, and therefore you're the one using it.

There is no advantage in loading it from a CDN - in fact, you're requesting a particular version, and as such it won't change. And it adds yet another network request. You don't need that.

Instead, include `list.min.js` in your extension's files, and amend the manifest:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["http://example.com/*"],
    "js": ["list.min.js", "includedstuff.js"],
    "css": ["list.css", /*...*/]
  }
```

This will load `List` in the context your code is executing; it will be invisible to the page itself, but it will not affect your code.

Comment: It worked by adding list.js to extension content, and injecting it in manifest, along with 'includedstuff.js'. Thank you for solving this for me, and thank you for the javascript lesson, will research the subject more. And sorry for my posting and editing blunders.